# How to get the elemts of an array from the input values that i use?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Please, if someone could tell me how i would be able to add the value of an input filed  inside of an array. And then the values of that element be able to display to the browser, and also now disapear when i refresh the page. The code that i tryed to use is below.

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name" ><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="add" id="btn">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var btn=document.getElementById("btn");
var all=[];

btn.onclick=function(){

    var name=document.getElementById("name").value;

   all.push(name);

    for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++){
        /* console.log(all[i]); */
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=all[i];

    }
}

</script>
```

thank You for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No loop is needed.** Just set the `.innerHTML` to all the array values, separated by an HTML `<br>` using the [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method. Nothing is needed to cause the list to start blank upon a page refresh either because when the page refreshes, the initial HTML will be re-parsed and the array data will be lost.

FYI: It's not a good idea to name a JavaScript variable `name` as it can conflict with the Global `name` property.

```js
var btn=document.getElementById("btn");
var all=[];

btn.onclick=function(){
  var item = document.getElementById("name").value;
  all.push(item);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = all.join("<br>");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name" ><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="add" id="btn">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: No the "name" variable i use it just as a test,but  the code works perferctly Scott

Comment: @eliot Great. Please up vote all helpful answers and consider marking this answer as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top-left of it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable & inside loop concat the value from the  array with this variable . Then outside loop use `innerHTML` and add the value of this variable to the dom

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var all = [];

btn.onclick = function() {
  let val = '';
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  all.push(name);

  for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    val += all[i] + ' '

  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = val;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="add" id="btn">

<p id="demo"></p>
```